# Design images via css

Tags: html, css

I have some question about design image on css. I have some logo and i want when click that image open official web site (that image). Is it possible? Thanks for all hints.

Comment: `<a href="http://www.officialurl.com"><img src="image.jpg"></a>`: Goodnight

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is ridiculously trivial 

Comment: Thanks but i import image via css and i have like this code on html: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css"/>`

Comment: this code is not even remotly what you want. And who is upvoting this question? ._0

Comment: I want help not describe of what i posted!

Comment: Haven't the answers below helped? If they haven't, the you should consider rewording your question for clarity or adding additional details.

Comment: And if one of the answers _has_ helped, then please accept it as correct.

Comment: Yes i accept already. Thanks for all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the image as a hyperlink. Use the code as follows.

```
<a href="www.linkofsite.com">
<img class="thecssclass">
</a>
```

where thecssclass is the class you have defined for the image in your stylesheet. For example,

```
.thecssclass
{
background-image:url('source.jpg');
}
```

Comment: Thanks but i import image via css and i have like this code on html:   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css"/>

Comment: please chek the updated answer given by me

Answer (score 1):

You're presumably using HTML for the markup, so try encapsulating the image within hyperlink tags:

```
<a href="your-site-url">
    <img src="path/to/image" />
</a>
```

As a note: just about any basic web programming tutorials could have demonstrated this. If you're struggling with these very elementary concepts, you would be well served to review some remedial materials on web development before you post to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

It's just simple:

`<a href="http://www.your_link.com"><img src="image.jpg"  alt="" /></a>`